# Upload files to Dropbox using a Dropbox Core API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on a simple chrome-extension that needs to upload files to the user's dropbox folder. I am using the simple AJAX requests as mentioned below to upload files, however it works for files with extensions such as `.txt, .json, .c, etc` i.e. files whose `mime type` is of type `text/plain` or similar type but all other file types such as pdfs, image files etc get corrupted and produce blank contents. What am I missing in uploading the files the correct way.

```
function startUpload()
{
    var folderPath = $(this).closest('tr').attr('path')+'/';
    var file = $("#upload_file")[0].files[0];
    if (!file){
        alert ("No file selected to upload.");
        return false;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        uploadFile(folderPath+file.name,evt.target.result,file.size,file.type);
    }
}

//function to upload file to folder
function uploadFile(filepath,data,contentLength,contentType){
    var url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto"+filepath;
    var headers = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken(),
        contentLength: contentLength,
    };
    var args = {
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        crossDomain: true,
        crossOrigin: true,
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: contentType,
        data : data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            getMetadata(filepath.substring(0,filepath.lastIndexOf('/')),createFolderViews);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR)
        {
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    };
    $.ajax(args);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is `reader.readAsTextFile(file, "UTF-8")`. If the file isn't a text file, this will misinterpret the contents. I *think* you want `reader.readAsBinaryString` or `reader.readAsArrayBuffer`. (I haven't tested it myself.)

**EDIT**

After testing this myself, I found that `readAsArrayBuffer` is what you need, but you also need to add `processData: false` as an option to `$.ajax` to prevent jQuery from trying to convert the data to fields in a form submission.

Also be sure to use `dataType: 'json'` to properly parse the response from the server.

Comment: I tried using the `arraybuffer` instead of `readAsText` but that further worsens the problem as the file size shown is zero in that case, at least with `readAsText` it shows a non-zero file size although incorrect many times. Using a `readAsArrayBuffer` won't be useful because in the end it also stores the data as a string.

Comment: yes I did, it behaves exactly like `readAsText` because the return type of both methods is `string`

Comment: [This article](https://www.newfangled.com/direct-javascript-dropbox-api-usage/) claims to have solved the problem, could you help me understanding it completely ?

Comment: after wasting hours, the combination of readAsArrayBuffer, dataType: 'json' & processData: false saved me. Thanks smarx!!