# Upload pdf to dropbox

Tags: javascript, encoding, ionic-framework, dropbox-api

Does any one implemented uploading pdf to dropbox, I am using dropbox api and file plugin.

I tried every method of file plugin (`ReadAsArrayBuffer`, `ReadAsBinaryString`, `ReadAsText`) using all that I am able to upload file to dropbox however format of PDF got corrupted upon downloading.

Please let me know if anybody has any solutions on it

```
function readDataUrl(file) {
  var reader= new FileReader({'blob': true});
  alert('in readDataUrl');
  console.log("file is",JSON.stringify(file));
   // var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        alert("reading completed");
        // console.log("Read as data URL");
       // console.log(new Uint8Array(evt.target.result));
        // Now upload this file to dropbox
        data = evt.target.result;
       // data = evt.target.result.match(/,(.*)$/)[1]
        uploadToDrpBox(data);

    }
   reader.readAsDataURL(file)

}




 function uploadToDrpBox (data){

  alert('in upload');
  // console.log(data);
  var deferred = $q.defer();
           $cordovaOauth.dropbox("App_ID").then(function(result){
              alert('in auth',result);
              // console.log(result);
              acc_token = result.access_token;

             $http.put('https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/'+$scope.docName+".pdf",data,{headers:{'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' +acc_token,'Conent-Length':'undefined','mimeType':'application/pdf','fileKey':"file"}}).then(function(res){
                 alert("in response");
                 // console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
                 deferred.resolve(res);
             }, function(error){
                 alert(JSON.stringify(error));
             });


       return deferred.promise;
       console.log("uploaded file");
    });
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288829/upload-files-to-dropbox-using-a-dropbox-core-api-in-javascript and see if it helps.

Comment: this is not working properly.pdf corrupted when download

Comment: Then share your code so people can help.

Comment: now i share code please suggest me my mistake